# Is it possible to create a modern-looking design with a dark theme?

Tags: website-design, color

I was asked a website redesign with two requirements:

- Inspired by Google Plus (clean, minimal, a lot of "white" space)
- Switchable between a White version and a Black version

Here's my problem:  The white version looks great and modern, but, no matter what I do, the black version resembles a 10-15 years old cheap website.

Is there a way I can make my dark theme still evoke a modern feel?

Comment: By a "black version," do you mean white text on a black background? Why would the client want that version?

Comment: Its Brainstorming or idea gathering, You should read http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the FAQ. Feel free to close it. About black/white, there are kind of users that prefer a dark theme instead of a lighter one.

Comment: Don't use BLACK black (#FFF), a dark grey can look very nice and sophisticated. Pure #FFF black looks like someone's Geocities site and results in awkward text colors.

Answer (score 1):

Take (hex) colors: Dark Background: `#313131`, light text: `#f5f5f5` This will lower the contrast a little bit, but is close to a `70/10 grey` and much easier to read. Further more it looks pretty classy.

I'd also go and choose some nice (cufon?) font for headings and such. Then use some thin `2px borders/hrs`, each `10-15% lighter/darker` as spacers (double in the sense of one half darker, other lighter, so you get a 3D effect, like it's graved in). You could also use the darker color to set a `10px (2px rounded) border` around images to make them stand out and take the lighter color as hover color.

Then use a) a grid and b) a limited set of overall colors: 5 colors are enough and you already got 2 grey and 2 light grey tones. Just add one single color for links or headings and you're perfect.

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe.com](http://www.adobe.com) would be a good example, I think. Also take a look at [TypeDNA.com](http://www.typedna.com). Both are dark themes, neither looks cheap, nor 15 years old.